# Group objects based on user in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, grouping

I'm trying to group a large amount of data that i received from my database as separate objects based on user.

The data i'm getting looks like this:

```
[ { ID: 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:19.960Z },
  { ID: '5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:24.179Z },
  { ID: '6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:18.249Z },
  { ID: '6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:11.230Z },
  { ID: '5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9',
    value: 0,
    created: 2018-05-02T11:33:34.705Z },
  { ID: '5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:00.049Z },
  { ID: 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:04.269Z },
  { ID: 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:02.365Z }
]
```

but I would like the output of the function to be grouped by the same ID like this

```
[[{ ID: 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:19.960Z },
{ ID: 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:04.269Z },
  { ID: 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:02.365Z }
],
[
  { ID: '6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:18.249Z },
  { ID: '6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:11.230Z }
],
[
  { ID: '5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:24.179Z },
  { ID: '5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9',
    value: 0,
    created: 2018-05-02T11:33:34.705Z },
  { ID: '5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
    created: 2018-05-02T13:21:00.049Z }
]]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in javascript?

I found a function that looks like this

```
function groupUserMood(xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
      (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
      return rv;
    }, {});
  };
```

But this also adds similar stuff together, which I wouldn't want.

Comment: That's invalid syntax. `created: 2018-05-02T13:21:19.960Z },`

Comment: That's a date I get from Firebase. Ignore the data values - that isn't part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of preserving the intermediate index can be solved in different ways. For example, this way:

```
var result = []
var keys = {}
data.forEach(function (e) {
  if (typeof keys[e.ID] === 'undefined') {
    result.push([])
    keys[e.ID] = result.length - 1
  }
  result[keys[e.ID]].push(e)
})
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/d0c41Lc8/ ]

Comment: This solution actually worked better for me since i'm using NodeJS, and `Object.values` doesn't exist prior to Node 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `.reduce` to group by identical `ID`s, and then `Object.values` to extract the arrays:

```js
const input = [{
    ID: 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
  },
  {
    ID: '5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
  },
  {
    ID: '6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
  },
  {
    ID: '6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
  },
  {
    ID: '5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9',
    value: 0,
  },
  {
    ID: '5feceb66ffc86f38d952786c6d696c79c2dbc239dd4e91b46729d73a27fb57e9',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
  },
  {
    ID: 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
  },
  {
    ID: 'd4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35',
    value: 13.450980186462402,
  }
];
const groupedInputObj = input.reduce((accum, item) => {
  const { ID } = item;
  if (!accum[ID]) accum[ID] = [];
  accum[ID].push(item);
  return accum;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(groupedInputObj);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Unfortunately `Object.values` isn't available in Node 6 (only from Node 7 and up)... any ideas on how to solve that part? I was thinking about doing `const output = Object.keys(groupedInputObj).map(function(key) {
            return groupedInputObj[key];
        });` but i didn't get that to work...

Answer (score 2):

You can group them like this:

```
const group = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.ID]) {
    acc[item.ID] = [];
  }

  acc[item.ID].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(group);
```

Your desired result will be in `result` variable.